# How to change conditional if select result is less than 10

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible with MySQL to change conditional statements if the select result isn't reaching the limit?

the code below will select the main category only, their cp.level is 0 but if they are only 3 category how can I change cp.level to 1 until reaches the limit

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        name, cd.category_id
        FROM oc_category_description cd
        LEFT JOIN oc_category_path cp ON (cd.category_id = cp.path_id)
        WHERE name LIKE 'с%'
        AND cp.level = 0 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: `AND cp.level in (0, 1) order by cp.level asc LIMIT 10`

Comment: @juergen d that work perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just filter the results of the query so `cp.level` is either 0 or 1, order by `cp.level` and keep the limit as 10. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        name, cd.category_id
        FROM oc_category_description cd
        LEFT JOIN oc_category_path cp ON (cd.category_id = cp.path_id)
        WHERE name LIKE 'с%'
        AND cp.level in (0, 1) ORDER BY cp.level ASC
        LIMIT 10
```

However if you're unsure it is going to reach the level of 1 and want to show level 2 as well, you can just remove `cp.level = 0` and order it by `ORDER BY cp.level ASC` instead.

If you want change the value you're filtering for on name based on the count, like you mentioned in your comment then you can do this:

```
WHERE (((subquery to get count) > 10 AND name LIKE 'с%') OR ((subquery to get count) < 10 AND name LIKE '%с'))
```

Comment: how can i change clause from LIKE 'c%' to LIKE '%c' if results are still less than 10 ?

Comment: @GameClubStreaming you'd probably have to do a subquery to find the count then something like this: `WHERE (((subquery to get count) > 10 AND name LIKE 'с%') OR ((subquery to get count) < 10 AND name LIKE '%с')) `